# Server.HtmlEncode is causing error to ODP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle, odp.net, html-encode

I am migrating a Framework v3.5 version to v4.5 and updating the `System.Data.OracleClient` with ODP.NET from Oracle.

In one part of the app, it is getting some value from QueryString, doing a `Server.HtmlEncode` and pushing into an oracle select statement where clause and running the statement through ODP.NET.

Now the problem is, it was working previously with the `System.Data.OracleClient`, but getting invalid identifier from Oracle with ODP.NET. Runs fine if I remove the `Server.HtmlEncode` but I am not allowed to expose the raw data to Oracle for security.

Need help!

```
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client

strStateIDs = Trim(Server.HtmlEncode(Context.Request.QueryString("STATE_IDS")))

strLVQuery = "SELECT <some columns> WHERE <some condition> AND <some column> IN (" & strInitStateIDs & ") ORDER BY <some columns>"
OracleDA.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
OracleDA.Fill(dataTable)
```

**Sample Data in `strStateIDs`:**

Without `Server.HtmlEncode`:

```
'ABC','XYZ','BLAH_BLAH'
```

After `Server.HtmlEncode`:

```
&#39;ABC&#39;,&#39;XYZ&#39;,&#39;BLAH_BLAH&#39;
```

**SOLUTION:**

Posting it as it might help someone later.. As Antonio Bakula pointed out, `HtmlEncode` encodes single quotes since ASP.NET 4.0

So, I did `strStateIDs = strStateIDs.Replace("&#39;", "'")` after `HtmlEncode` to work around this issue.

Comment: beware of SQL injection ! And could you add example what is in STATE_IDS variable when this doesn't work

Comment: Try using bind variables.

Comment: @AntonioBakula Please see edit.. I have added sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't see any need for HtmlEncode for string that will be used in SQL select. So my advice would be remove HtmlEncode.

Reason why this is not working anymore is documented here:
http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770143

btw. your code is open to SQL injection, please use parameters, details here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

Comment: okay, so the single quotes are also encoded now, thus the oracle error.. There must be some reason why the `HtmlEncode` is used, the records in the rows must be stored as encoded too.. So 'll have to work around this somehow.. Would be helpful if you can give me a hint

Comment: can't think of anything, only reason for encoding would be to encode URL and then later decode it for SQL query. But your case is other way around

Answer (score 0):

Once you HtmlEncode the content it becomes

```
"&#39;ABC&#39;,&#39;XYZ&#39;,&#39;BLAH_BLAH&#39;"
```

As you can see there are semi colons in your query as it will look like this now.

```
"SELECT <some columns> WHERE <some condition> AND <some column> IN ("&#39;ABC&#39;,&#39;XYZ&#39;,&#39;BLAH_BLAH&#39;") ORDER BY <some columns>"
```

That makes the db assume you are terminating your statements and starting new ones.

I assume there is a reason you are not using `SqlParameter`s or their Oracle equivalent. Assuming you want to push on with this string based options, I would do this in C#.

```
   strLVQuery = string.Format(@"SELECT <some columns> WHERE <some condition> AND <some column> IN ('{0}') ORDER BY <some columns>",strStateIDs);
```

Maybe that will help you come up with a VB solution.

Comment: the `IN ('{0}')` or Oracle Parameters will build the `IN` statement in a wrong way. The entire parameter inside `IN` will be treated as a single string in the statement, but its not the intended way.